# Read from System.err in Java?

Tags: java, stream, pipe

I intend to create a "stream-processor" in java

I will be piping the output of a program as it logs output to the console to a java program which will add "markup" to the data as it comes in and put it in a file.

The "markup" will be based on where the program outputs the data.

If the source program outputs to error stream  I want to handle the markup in one way in my java program

If the source program outputs to output stream I want to handle the markup differently in my java program

I am able to read from System.in. 
But here I would also like to read from System.err of the original program

How do I do that ?

Comment: "outputs to output stream"; `System.out`? Reading from `System.in` makes sense as it is an input stream. Reading from `System.out` doesn't. It sounds like you're determining when to output to these streams, so couldn't you just handle it at that time?

Comment: Hold on. `System.in` is your process' standard input, you cannot read the input from any other program in there, except if you pipe another process into it. For capturing another process' stdout and stderr, you should have a look at `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Source Program's output is the output to the stdout (unix outputstream). And I pipe that so, it becomes my Java program's input stream(Unix stdin). Source Program's error goes to unix stderr. I want to read the stderr without actually redirecting strerr to stdout.

Comment: OK, so you want to be able to capture stderr separately? Tough call... What you can do is use a `ProcessBuilder` in pure Java and launch the process you want instead of piping the input.

Comment: @fge Yes I can. I am doing it now. Unix pipe Program1 | Program2 turns stdout of Program1 to stdin for Program2. What I want is to create a BufferedReader object that reads Stderr of Program1 and then do a line by line processing of it.

Comment: @fge Yes. I see. So will I be able to read Stdout and stderr using processbuilder ? Do you have a link that I can look at to understand how to do this ?

Comment: Well, the first link I'd point to is [the javadoc for `ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It is immensely configurable (for instance, set the working directory, modify the environment etc), so any further link than that would only restrict your imagination :)

Comment: @fge Haha! Should have saw that coming. Thanks for the idea.